# "des intervalles" ou bien "un intervalle"

Tags: orthographe, accord

Ecrit-on :
"Des événements surgissant tous dans des intervalles de temps rapprochés."
ou bien :
"Des événements surgissant tous dans un intervalle de temps rapproché." ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La deuxième n'a pas trop de sens (rapproché de quoi ?), peut-être veut-on dire "surgissant tous dans un court intervalle de temps".

La première parait  possible. On pourrait aussi dire :

> ...surgissant tous à une grande fréquence.

> ...surgissant tous dans de courts intervalles de temps.

> ...surgissant tous dans des périodes de temps rapprochées.

> ...surgissant en rafales successives.

> ...surgissant en salves rapprochées.

D'autre part, il me semble qu'un événement *apparaît*, *se produit* ou *survient* plus qu'il ne *surgit*.

Comment: "survient" paraît plus approprié en effet. Merci bien. Etonnamment, le mot "événement" semble déjà contenir tous ces verbes qui l'annoncent ensuite.

Answer (score 0):

Si "Des événements surgissant tous dans un intervalle de temps rapproché." doit être une idée complète on se retrouve à écrire du non-sens parce que un seul intervalle doit être rapproché de quelque chose. Il s'agit alors de « des événements surgissant tous dans des intervalles de temps rapprochés ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapproch%C3%A9)) − [Avec subst. au plur.] **Très proches l'un de l'autre, les uns des autres, serrés.**
> Dents, yeux rapprochés.
>
> - Les sourcils étaient droits, rapprochés (signe de tempérament coléreux, disait MlleGénolain) (Daniel-Rops,Mort, 1934, p. 23).
> - L'escalier avec ses piliers trop lourds et trop rapprochés. Que tout cela manque d'air, de grâce (Green,Journal, 1950, p. 349).

*Exemple*

- En périodes de vacance, des événements surgissant tous dans des intervalles de temps rapprochés sont la raison qui explique que certaines histoires sont négligées.

Si "Des événements surgissant tous dans un intervalle de temps rapproché." n'est pas une idée complète elle peut être insérée dans un contexte où elle prend un sens.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rapproch%C3%A9)) − [Avec subst. au sing. ou au plur.] **Qui est à peu de distance de quelqu'un, de quelque chose, proche.**
>
> - Depuis trois dimanches, je ne suis allée à la messe. Heureux ceux qui ont l'église rapprochée! (E. de Guérin,Lettres, 1846, p. 504).
> - Le soleil est à 150 millions de kilomètres de la terre et (...) les distances des étoiles les plus rapprochées sont des centaines de mille fois plus grandes encore (H. Poincaré,Valeur sc., 1905, p. 165).

*Exemple*

- Lorsque il y a peu d'histoires à écrire les journalistes se rabattent sur d'autres tâches et alors des événements surgissant tous dans un intervalle de temps rapproché causent un problème.